# How do I put text on the side of an interactive map with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to finish a project but I am stuck on the final step.
All I want to do is put some text on the side of an interactive google map. However so far no matter what I have tried the text stays underneath. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!--Reach out section begins-->
  <section id="reach-out" class="contact">
<h2 class="section-title secondary-border">
    <p>Reach Out</h2></p>
<div class="contact/info">
  <iframe 
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d12182.
    30520634488!2d-74.0652613!3d40.2407219!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!
    2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1561060983193!5m2!1sen!2sus"
    >
  </iframe>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Pump Buddy</h3>
    <p>
      Any questions or concerns before signing up? <br />  
      Let us know, and we will be happy to talk to you.
    </p> 
    <address><!-- <address>: Defines the contact information
         for the author or owner of the document or parent element.-->
      55 Main Street<br />
      Some Town, CA<br />
      12345<br />
      P: 555.PUMP.BUDZ (555.786.2839)<br />
      E: <a href= "mailto:info@pumpbuddy.io"> info@pumpbuddy.io</a>
      <!-- Using the mailto: prefix in the anchor tag's href attribute 
        instructs the browser to open the default mail client application
         upon clicking the link and then populates the address field with 
         the email address listed in the href value. -->
    </address>
</div>
  </section>
  </body>
```

and this is the corresponding CSS:

```
/* REACH OUT STYLES START */
.contact {
  text-align: center;
  background: #024e76;
}

.contact h2 {
  color: #fce138;
}

.contact-info iframe { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
/* This is a potentially 
dangerous choice due to possible side effects 
(unless a global rule is needed). By using the 
class (contact-info) as the CSS selector, also called a class 
selector, we can safely target the <iframe> that 
is a descendant or child of the element with this class.*/
 
.contact-info div {
  width: 410px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 30px 0 0 60px;
  color: white;
}
.contact-info h3 {
  color: #fce138;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.contact-info p, .contact-info address {
  margin: 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
}
.contact-info a {
  color: #fce138;
}

/* REACH OUT STYLES END */
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` and set `position` property to `absolute` or `fixed`  for the text you want to display over the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">

      <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Reach Out</h2>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-right">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d12182.
                         30520634488!2d-74.0652613!3d40.2407219!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!
                         2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1561060983193!5m2!1sen!2sus"
                    ></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="">
            <h3>Pump Buddy</h3>
            <p>Any questions or concerns before signing up? <br> Let us know, and we will be happy to talk to you.</p> 
            <address>
              55 Main Street<br>
              Some Town, CA<br>
              12345<br>
              P: 555.PUMP.BUDZ (555.786.2839)<br>
              E: <a href= "mailto:info@pumpbuddy.io"> info@pumpbuddy.io</a>
            </address>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```